# XMLRPC call from jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, android, xml-rpc

I have a HTML file with little bit of javascript in it. Its not in any server. I have that file on my desktop. I have enabled the services module and want to do stuff from the HTML file.

```
$.post(
"http://example.com/services/xmlrpc",
{methodName: node.load; nid: 1},
function(data){
alert("Data: " + data);
}
);
```

Now, as far as I know, it will work. BUT, when I put (upload) the same HTML file in my android phone, will it work??

Please show some light in this!

Thanks

Comment: How come you didn't try to upload it to your Android phone and run it before asking the question here?

Comment: Well, I don't have an android phone. I'll try to check in my friend's phone this evening.. Anyway, i check the code from my desktop, its not working. the data is an object.. how to print that in alert?

Comment: Agree. I do not see anything suspicious and AFAIK JS works well on Android mobiles (within appropriate browser - that already the default one is). So move the HTML file to Your phone and give it a try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the reponse is an object - I advise to use Firebug extension in Firefox and the Console tab where You can see what the response looks like (I suppose it will be encoded to JSON) - it should look like `{"property":"value", "property2":"value2", ...}`. Then You can acces the properties like

```
$.post(
    "http://example.com/services/xmlrpc",
        {methodName: node.load; nid: 1},
        function(data){
            alert("Property 1: " + data.property);
        }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understood this part. Unfortunately still I am struggling with the code. Anyway, my biggest doubt is, you cannot make cross domain calls from AJAX. Like, if the page loads from www.abcd.com, you cannot make ajax calls to www.efgh.com ------ Is the same thing applicable in XML-RPC (the one we are discussing here) ????

Comment: If this is the problem and You want to call an XML-RPC procedure on different domain, use own PHP script that will be called by Your AJAX and that will call the cross-domain XML-RPC procedure using CURL or get_file_contents(URL) for example... Using PHP (or other server-side programming languages) You can call webservices on different domains (that is why webservices exist :-) ).

Comment: OKay I understand that :) Now, the client browser detects a request is cross domain or not from the originating domain (in the above example, its www.abcd.com). BUT, what if the html file is opened from the local device (without visiting any URL)?? yes, there will the file path though....

Comment: Yes, this will bring us the problem - You cannot run PHP scripts on android (AFAIK, or can You?), so this is suitable only for some webhosting with own domain and visiting via webbrowser (whether from PC or a mobile device)... Or for Android You can build an application (in Java) that will do the stuff instead of JS... :-)

Comment: hmm.. After so much discussion, we came back to the same point! That it wont work.. Basically I am making an android app (jquerymobile) which can be downloaded (from android market) and installed in the device. So, when my javascript runs on the phone, there is no way to make XML-RPC calls to different servers.. Any other idea/solutions?

Comment: YES! If You are working with jQuery within an android app, you should be able to call a "webpage" (within a WebView? - do not know, have never worked with WebView yet) that will call Your local JAVA method and that will do the job (calling of XML_RPC)... I changed the drupal tag for android.

Comment: Hmmm.. Well, I have to make the app for android and iPhone. I think webView (& similar thing for iPhone) is the only option to us :( And if I put the web-app in my XML-RPC server, then I don't even need to create a PHP proxy in between, because there wont be any cross domain calls! Well, something is better than nothing ;) And in this case, the webView will do the job... Thanks a lot :)